# Creating a shortcut passing arguments to shell32.dll using Powershell

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing, rundll32

So I am trying to make a 'create shortcut' script to generate a link on my users desktop to take them directly to the "Add Printer Wizard" in Windows 10.  Programatically speaking, I am *pretty sure* it is not possible but it is a directive from above.  When the script runs, the Arguments field get dropped.

## UPDATE

I can create this manually, but not programatically.

*Help Me StackOverFlow ... You're our only hope*

```
$sArguments = "shell32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL PrintersFolder"
$AppLocation = "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe"
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$env:PUBLIC\Desktop\UAT Devices and Printers.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $AppLocation
$Shortcut.Arguments = $sArguments
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "devicecenter.dll,0"
$Shortcut.Description ="UAT Devices and Printers"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory ="C:\Windows\System32"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

I feel stupid asking, but can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: [`#requires -RunAsAdministrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires)

Comment: I was planning to make sure that it was running in an Administrative Context, but good catch! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to trigger the `Add Printer Driver Wizard`, here's the fixed version of your code (the arguments are differents, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui):

```
$sArguments = "printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /id"
$AppLocation = "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe"
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$env:PUBLIC\Desktop\UAT Devices and Printers.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $AppLocation
$Shortcut.Arguments = $sArguments
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "devicecenter.dll,0"
$Shortcut.Description ="UAT Devices and Printers"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory ="C:\Windows\System32"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: The code was exhibiting the same issue until I ran it in a clean test environment.  Works perfectly!  Thanks for the link as well, I am using it to spawn some all-new script processes.